# Listar datos en un DataTable con ajax

Tags: python, django

Buenas les cuento mi problema, toda ayuda sera bien recibida, gracias por adelantado.

A ver tengo que poner varias partes de mi codigo para que puedan entender la situacion, pero es solo un pequeño problema.

Estoy intentando listar un conjunto de datos, usando ajax y datatable. Pero uno de los campos del modelo que tengo que listar, es de tipo dateTimeField ( FechaDeEntrada=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)) , y cuando envio estos datos a mi ajax para listarlos, llegan todos los datos del modelo, excepto este.

Este dato desaparece justo cuando paso el modelo por el metodo (model_to_dict) para convertirlo en un objeto de tipo json.
Pero es que si no lo convierto a json no puedo listarlo. O al menos no se hacerlo.

Views.py

```
class PerfilView(ListView):
    model = Orden
    template_name = "OficinaCliente/perfil.html"
    context_object_name="lista_ordenes"
    

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data=[]
        try:
            if request.POST['action'] == 'listar':
                
                ListaOrdenes= Orden.objects.filter(cliente_id=request.user.id,estado__in=['Pendiente','En Proceso'])
                este = model_to_dict(ListaOrdenes[0])
               
                for i in ListaOrdenes:
                    data.append(i.toJSON())                    

            else:
                data['error'] = "No has seleccionado ninguna accion"

        except Exception as e:
            data ={"error":str(e)}
    
        
        return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

codigo ajax y datatable

```
function CargarTabla(){
    
    tablacliente = $('#data').DataTable({
        
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        destroy: true,
        deferRender: true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "language":{
            
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ning�n dato disponible en esta tabla =(",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "�ltimo",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        },
        "buttons": {
            "copy": "Copiar",
            "colvis": "Visibilidad"
        }
        },
   
    ajax:{

        url:window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            'action':'listar',
        },
        dataSrc: ""

    },
    columns:[
        {'data': 'id'},
        {'data': 'tipoDeServicio'},
        {'data': 'FechaDeEntrada'},
        {'data': 'FechaLimite'},
        {'data': 'estado'},
        {'data': 'estado'},
        {'data': 'estado'},
       

    ],
    
    columnDefs:[
       
        {
            targets: [2],
            class: 'text-center',
            orderable: false,
            render:function(data,type,row){
                return data

            }
        },

    ],
 
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        //alert('tabla cargada')    
      }

});


}
```

models.py

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    tipoDeServicio = models.ForeignKey(Servicio,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cliente=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profesional=models.ForeignKey(Profesional,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    FechaDeEntrada=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    FechaLimite=models.DateTimeField()
    cliente_TrabajoTerminado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profesional_TrabajoTerminado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmacion_de_pago=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def toJSON(self):
        return model_to_dict(self)
```

Comment: Esta respuesta te puede ayudar, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162819/1612654